# greatest N per group with padding

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I've been trying to solve this problem over the weekend, without luck so far. I have two tables:

`TopOffers:`

```
OfferId    RetailerId      Order
1          38              0
2          8               3
3          17              2
4          22              1
```

And `Offers:`

```
Id     RetailerId       Name            Description          etc...
1      3                Strawberry      Red and smelly
2      38               Cookie          Crunchy
3      17               Onion           Of the nice kind
4      22               Apple           Cheap
5      8                Toothbrush      Lasts extra long!
```

My goal is to get the top 10 Offers for each Retailer ID. The order in which they should be listed is specified by the `Order` field in the TopOffer table (Sort order is Ascending). On top of that, the result should be padded to 10 offers when there are less than 10 TopOffer records for a retailer. The TopOffer table always contains 10 or less records per retailer.

So far I've managed to get this going, which works (I realize it doesn't get the top 10, but rather everything that's in the TopOffer table, which is alright, since the TopOffer table is always equal to or smaller than the top 10 for any retailer):

```sqlite
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
    SELECT o.Id, to.`Order` FROM Offer AS o
    LEFT JOIN TopOffer AS to
    ON o.Id = to.OfferId
) AS a,
(
    SELECT o.*, to.`Order` FROM Offer AS o
    LEFT JOIN TopOffer AS to
    ON o.Id = to.OfferId
) AS b
WHERE a.`Order` >= b.`Order` AND a.Id = b.Id
GROUP BY b.RetailerId, b.Id
HAVING Count(1) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY RetailerId, `Order` ASC
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any way of padding the result of this query with offers that don't have an entry in the TopOffer table if there aren't 10 TopOffer records for that retailer.

My sincerest thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The `RetailerID`s in the two tables do not match.

Comment: The actual data I listed was more of an example, theoretically not all retailers need have entries in the TopOffer table

Answer (score 0):

If you create a virtual table with numbers 1-10 you can left join to your results to get 10 of each

```
   select number, results.*
   from
       (select 1 as number union select 2 union select 3 ... union select 10) numbers
            left join
       (your query here) results
            on numbers.number = results.rank
```

Comment: rank is a field name in this context, not the function

Comment: I think I explained it poorly in my initial post; Wouldn't the solution you suggest here result in Offer records with NULL values for those cases where there are less than 10 TopOffers for a retailer?

I need to pad the result with actual offers from the Offer table in the case that there are less than 10 TopOffers for a retailer. That's why I've been LEFT joining Offers and TopOffers so that I still have the full set of Offers (most with NULL values for the TopOffer fields) to perform the grouping magic over.

Comment: @RogierPennink Ah, I see. What you need to do is a `union` between top offers and all offers, ordered so that top offers are always first, and then take the top 10 of those.